# Google cloud container engine vs normal vm

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Short question about the container engine: why should I use it rather than just handle my docker containers in a normal VM (in compute engine)? Could save a little money, this way...

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a small scale, running containers in normal VMs is fine. Google even offers a [container optimized image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/vm-image/) that makes this really easy. And it's definitely less expensive than running a Kubernetes cluster (either in Google Container Engine or yourself).

What's really powerful about Kubernetes / GKE is the cluster management API. It allows you to *introspect* all of the containers running on your compute, either using a CLI/UI or by other programs. With a normal VM, to find out all of the containers that you are running you'd either need to repeatedly ssh into each of your VMs and run `docker ps` or specifically build your containers to "phone home" to a central container version authority (which won't be possible if you want to use off-the-shelf containers). With Kubernetes, you can say `kubectl get pods` and with a single command know everything that you are running. You can use constructs built for application management like Deployments (or `kubectl rolling-update`) to push new versions of your containers without restarting any VMs. And you get cluster-wide logging and monitoring for your containers as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general issue of using your own infrastructure, or a pay-for-service approach. This is probably best explained by economy (do you have memory upfront for a big investment in own hardware to create VM on?)
But there are technical issues as well: with a paid service you are free from issues of providing power, or connectivity, or hardware maintenance, or lower-level management, or... Of course this also means that you can not influence how (quick, expensive, fitting to your needs, etc) these issues are solved by your provider.
In short: with VM you have more freedom, but also more work and possibly higher upfront costs (also **cost of your own labor**, so it takes **more time to start** the essential part of your project). With paid service the total **financial** costs may be higher, but costs are spread in time. You have less freedom about the platform, but this also means you can concentrate on higher-level issues related to your specific application - and you can start thinking about them sooner.
You could also consider BOTH - to have e.g. additional computing capacity for disaster-recovery, or testing, or backup.